# As Java intermediate programmer how can i contribute to Ubuntu?

Tags: programming, contributing

I'm intermediate Java programmer and C at beginner level, I'm willing to contribute to Ubuntu, how can I start and where to start from?

Pls explain me in detail.Interested in small projects.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these links to help you get started with contributing to Ubuntu:

https://community.ubuntu.com/t/contribute/26

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContributeToUbuntu

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopers